# How to get an instance of unitycontainer?

Tags: silverlight, mvvm, inversion-of-control, unity-container

I've developing a Silverlight application, and I've introduced `Unity` into it.

The problem I have is I don't know how to get an instance of container.

I create this intance in `ApplicationStartup` method on the `App`

```
_container = new UnityContainer();
            _container.RegisterType<IMyAppServiceAgent, MyAppServiceAgent>(new InjectionConstructor(OriginalHandlerId, W2OGuid, ServiceEndpointAddr));
```

and I write a getter

```
public IUnityContainer Container
        {
            get { return _container; }
        }
```

Everything works fine, and this how I use my container:

```
    public static void CreateMemberSearch()
    {
        if (_memberSearch == null)
        {

            _memberSearch =
                new MemberSearchViewModel((App.Current as App).Container.Resolve<IMyAppServiceAgent>());

        }
    }
```

Above example is from ViewModelLocator (from `MVVM Light Toolkit`).

I need to know how to refactor my code to go along with the `IOC` principles.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code shown above implements the [ServiceLocator anti-pattern](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorIsAnAntiPattern.aspx). You should never call the container directly.

The container is setup in the [Composition Root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot.aspx). For a Silverlight application that would be your ApplicationStartup method or a dedicated bootstrapper like in [Caliburn.Micro](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com).

This container instance is called exactly once to resolve your main view oder viewmodel (depending on wether you use a view first or viewmodel first approach).

And that should be it. You should never call your container again. If a class depends on some other component: inject that component using [constructor injection](http://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html). If that class needs to create other objects: inject a factory. Unity has a nice feature called [automatic factories](http://www.tavaresstudios.com/Blog/post/Unity-20-Automatic-Factories.aspx)

---

Update

If the `ViewModelLocator` is part of your infrastructure and you never use it directly in your application code ... maybe. Please see my comment on @MikePost's question.

Comment: thanks for your reply Sebastian. So If I add IUnityContainer to ViemModelLocator constructor it would be acceptable?

Comment: a question for Sebastian.  i use the container.Resolve<Type>()  to create instances of my objects ( for example when lazy loading).  Are you saying this shouldnt be done?

Comment: Interesting, especially the anti-pattern link.  But how do you resolve the problems that were solved by the view-model-locator pattern using a static gateway to a DI container?

Comment: @MikePost I'm not familiar with MVVM Light but other frameworks like Caliburn.Micro "solve" that issue by making the locator part of the infrastructure. It's still the same pattern but your application code **never** calls the container directly. The framework/infrastructure does. I know it sounds more like legal blabla but it really makes a big difference wether it's the glue that keeps your application together that interoperates with your DI container or if your app code goes there and just pulls whatever it thinks it might need from said container.

Comment: @Anton If you want to use lazy loading inject a factory instead. Unity can generate factories on-the-fly. E.g. if you need an `IService` don't pull it from the container but add a ctor parameter of type `Func<IService>`. Unity (and several other containers) know how to generate the delegate for you if you tell them to which implementation `IService` should be mapped.

Comment: I dug into Caliburn.Micro's solution and it is pretty nice (especially since they thought about the design time problem).  I need to see if Unity offers something similar (don't think so).

Comment: @MikePost Unity is not a UI framework like Caliburn. But you can plug in Unity as the default container that Caliburn.Micro uses. There is a sample of a Unity bootstrapper for Caliburn in the [TecX project](http://tecx.codeplex.com).You can find the code in _TecX.CaliburnEx.UnityBootstrapper_.

Comment: ServiceLocator is not an antipattern. That example is a straw man construction.  That's not what ServiceLocator's are meant to do, so of course it looks like a bad pattern when demonstrated that way.  ServiceLocator's are used when we have multiple unique implementations of a common denominator and need to access a specific behavior based on some contextual information.

Comment: @AaronLS The only excuse to use a SL is when you don't control the instantiation of an object. Otherwise injecting a factory you can provide with the contextual information it requires to chose a specific behavior is the preferred solution. A factory is the designated place to make such decisions. You can (try to) pull any arbitrary object from a SL. Especially someone new to your project will ALWAYS abuse a SL that way. Just because he can. That makes it an antipattern.

Comment: @SebastianWeber What you describe here is service locator pattern: "contextual information it requires to chose a specific behavior" So you are saying that implementation is fine? But of course you can choose to create the context to generate the desired concrete implementation, thus as you say "pull any arbitrary object from a SL. Especially someone new to your project will ALWAYS abuse a SL that way."  I've not found that to be the case. I can prove your assertion false as soon as a single developer doesn't abuse the SL, because you used "always" as a qualifier.

Comment: Once you've implemented the SL pattern properly, usually new features are implemented without touching any of the code that deals with the SL. *E.g.* I have a plugin pattern setup for payment gateways. Various tenant's have a data driven configuration that selects the payment gateway implementation appropriate for their site.  Dev's implement new payment gateways by implementing the appropriate interfaces. They never touch any of the instantiation code because all of that plumbing is in place already and completely data driven. So they never leverage the SL for direct instantiation.